# SAS to Oracle: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

Running this code in SAS to Oracle:

```
rsubmit;
Proc sql;
    &c_oradb;
    Create table immB as
    SELECT * from connection to oracle
    (Select b.ID, b.SYSDATE, 
    case when ID>0 then 'IMM' End as SOURCE /*creating  a variable to label source file */
    From hpmdcd a, omdb.medta b
    Where a.CODE=b.CODE
    AND   '1/1/2008'd =< SYSDATE <= '12/31/2016'd 
    Order by ID, SYSDATE);
    DISCONNECT from oracle;
Quit;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator. SQL statement

Comment: Is this number 2 in a long running sequence of posts asking us to spot your syntax errors?

Comment: Hi APC in the code I am trying to join two tables. The table hepmdc was created as a part of a proc sql code and would be stored as a sas data table. But omdb.medta is a table in Oracle database. Is it possible to join these two using this code or should some changes be made? Even if we ignore the date statement. I am new to using oracle through SAS having only programmed in SAS before and am facing problems. Thanks for your support!

Comment: `'1/1/2008'd` is a SAS date literal, which isn't going to work in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

```
AND   '1/1/2008'd =< SYSDATE <= '12/31/2016'd
```

There are 3 things wrong with just this statement.

1. You can't use 2 relational operators together. Use between
2. `d` after date is not required as it will work as column alias which may be needed in select but not while comparing.
3. Comparing `string` with `date` is not correct.

Use

```
AND sysdate between date '2008-01-01' and date '2016-12-31'
```

`date '2008-01-01'` is equivalent to `to_date('2008-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')`

Also, although it won't give you any error, instead of using classing comma separated tables, use proper `join` syntax. Something like.

```
FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 
  on t1.somecolumn=t2.somecolumn
```

I am looking just the sql query. Not sure on SAS part.